# Cosmos DB creation exception - Forbidden (403); Substatus: 5300 with AAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cosmosdb, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to create Cosmos Database in C# with AAD.

CosmosClient CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync method is throwing Cosmos exception as

"Forbidden (403); Substatus: 5300; Request blocked by Auth cosmos-eus2-01 : The given request [POST /dbs] cannot be authorized by AAD token"

Microsoft document says "Using Microsoft Entra identities blocks any non-data operation".
Here is the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-forbidden#non-data-operations-are-not-allowed

Creating CosmosClient with account key is the only workaround for this error?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You cannot perform Management Plane operations with AAD credentials on a Data Plane SDK.

As the documentation link you provided says, which points to https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#permission-model:

> You cannot use any Azure Cosmos DB data plane SDK to authenticate management operations with a Microsoft Entra identity. Instead, you must use Azure role-based access control through one of the following options

For .NET, it is [Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB/)

Comment: Matias Quaranta - Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.